# OpenUI5 PDFViewer throws DOM error on displaying pdf file

Tags: pdf, dom, sapui5

I would like to use the sap.m.PDFViewer to display my PDF files which are included to the UI5 project. The file is found and loaded but the viewer displays the default error message and in the console I find:

> Error: Underlying iframe was not found in DOM.

My XML view snippet:

```xml
<PDFViewer
   displayType="Auto"
   source="{/fileSource}"
   <layoutData>
      <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
   </layoutData>
</PDFViewer>
```

The URL is created like this:

```js
this.sSourcePath = sap.ui.require.toUrl("com/myapp/docs/File.pdf");
this.oModel = new JSONModel({
  fileSource: this.sSourcePath
});
this.setModel(this.oModel);
```

In the "Network" tab I can see that the file is requested and loaded so the path is correct.

I tried several versions including 1.108.19 and 1.114.8 but this does not change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding your Model to your view. Please try it with `this.getView().setModel(this.oModel)` and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi, this does not change anything. What's weird is the fact that the busy indicator for the PDF viewer is shown for a couple of seconds. Only afterwards, the DOM related error is thrown in the console.

Comment: That is odd, I've tried several things to "break" it, but can't reproduce your error. Could you tell me more details about your application? What container is there around the PDF Viewer, what type of device are you using, and is the namespace of your path correct? Also have you tried removing the layoutData? I just tested it on a plain View, perhaps that's where the issues are coming from.